Novel manhwa in which the female protagonist runs away from an orphanage that was selling children
The female protagonist is in an orphanage that have talented in magic and she discovered that the orphanage has been selling the children, so she runs away. By the way, she also has a wand that was left by her mother. When she was running from the orphanage she being kidnapped and met the prince or the male protagonist and she rescued all the children there.
The cover has two characters; the female protagonist and the blonde male protagonist. Please help me. 

Did you actually read this as a novel or a comic?

Also, did you mean to say that the orphanage was for children talented in magic?

And did you mean to say that the female protagonist was kidnapped after running away from the orphanage, or that she ran away to avoid being kidnapped?

I read this as a novel

No the kid in the orphanage is somewhat have magic but not all of them have talented

If i remembered correctly she try to runaway then being kidnapped

Did the prince rescue her from the kidnappers?

The plot partially match Otome Game no Heroine de Saikyou Survival however this is novel and the part you remember is 2 different arc. There is also arc she survive in a town alone and get adopted + training and then the kidnap arc. Also no cover female + blonde male

This is an korean light novel so it definitely not include otome plot in its
